# link (a href) in bootstrap dropdown menu does not function

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, dropdown, popper.js

This issue seems to be ancient and a lot of topics about it. yet none of the solutions are working for me at the moment.
I have a header with the user name - which is a dropdown menu. in dropdown list i have a link which refuses to work:

```
                   <div class="dropdown dib">
                        <div class="header-icon" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <span class="user-avatar">{{ user }}
                                <i class="ti-angle-down f-s-10"></i>
                            </span>
                            <div class="drop-down dropdown-profile dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                                <div class="dropdown-content-body">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <a data-target="/accounts/logout/" href="/accounts/logout/">
                                                <i class="ti-power-off"></i>
                                                Logout
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Following scripts have been imported:

```
    <!-- jquery -->
    <script src="{% static 'assets/js/lib/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'assets/js/lib/jquery.nanoscroller.min.js' %}"></script>
    <!-- nano scroller -->
    <script src="{% static 'assets/js/lib/menubar/sidebar.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'assets/js/lib/preloader/pace.min.js' %}"></script>
    <!-- sidebar -->

    <script src="{% static 'assets/js/lib/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'assets/js/scripts.js' %}"></script>
```

this is bootstrap v4.3.1 in 2020 and bootstrap.bundle is supposed to include popper.js
these static imports are related to django, so don't worry they are correct!

According to other similar posts, using the data-target attribute on the href should solve the non-functioning link... but it doesn't.

What i might be missing?

Comment: Are you able to create a working example?  Unfortunately from what you shared it looks like everything should be working.

Comment: Thank you for the input xDaevax, at the moment i haven't yet been able to fix this issue. I am wondering if the webpack-bundle-loader which is used for development in conjunction with django is causing this issue.

Comment: What specifically is the error / behavior you see?  Doesn't work could mean many things.   Is the href attribute populated when you view source / inspect?  Does the link appear on the screen for you?  If the link appears, what happens (specifically) when you click it?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
href="accounts/logout/"
```

Comment: unfortunately makes no difference

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Unfortunately, code-only answers with no explanation are not helpful.  Please include information about how your answer provides a solution to the problem.